# python3: ImportError: No module named xxxx

Tags: python, package, importerror

I am new to Python and I am trying to understand a problem, which I see when creating a package. 
I have the following file structure: (Working-Directory is /my/Python/jmLib2)

```
/my/Python/jmLib2
     |--- Phone
     |      |--- __init__.py
     |      |--- Pots.py
     |- Test2.py

---------------------------------
cat ./jmLib2/Pots.py
#!/usr/bin/python

def Pots():
    print ("I'm Pots Phone")

---------------------------------
cat ./jmLib2/__init__.py
from Pots import Pots

---------------------------------
cat ./Test2.py
#!/usr/bin/python
from Phone import Pots

import os.path
print ("OS:"+str(os.path))

Pots()
```

---

When I now do:

```
python2 Test2.py
OS:<module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
    I'm Pots Phone*
```

GREAT...BUT, if I do:

```
python3 Test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Phone import Pots
  File "/home/juergen/my/Python/jmLib2/Phone/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Pots import Pots
ImportError: No module named 'Pots'
```

I am working with PyDev under Eclipse. PyDev reports me inside the **init**.py file an "Unresolved import: Pots"-error. 
I have the same traceback-problem under PyDev and bash.

Again, I am new to Python... so it is maybe a very stupid mistake.
But can someone explain me, the difference between python2 and python3.4? 
Do I have to modify the PYTHONPATH? Why?

Greetings
Juergen

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**TL;DR:** [Relative imports are gone](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingPythonToPy3k#relative-imports). Use absolute imports instead.

Either use:

```
from Phone.Pots import Pots
```

or:

```
from .Pots import Pots
```

---

The problem occurs because `Pots` is part of the `Phone` package: there is no module named `Pots`, there's a module named `Phone.Pots`.

Python 2 had a feature called [*relative imports*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) that let you write `import Pots` even if that was not technically correct.

Relative imports however are a source of [problems and confusion](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html):

- Who reads the code cannot immediately say whether the import is from a package or not.
- How come the module is named `Phone.Pots`, but I can use `import Pots`? This is highly inconsistent.
- What if the submodule shadows a name of another module?

For these reasons, relative imports were removed from Python 3.

---

You can get rid of relative imports from Python 2 by using a [`__future__` import](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: Andrea: Thankyou for the fast and detailed answer.